# Динамически присваивать тип C# рефлексия

Tags: c#, рефлексия, c#-8.0

всем привет.
Можно ли используя рефлексию динамически присвоить тип значению и установить его полю объекта?
При

```
typeProperty.SetValue(book, (Тут нужен каст)getValue);
```

Тут идет распаковка а распаковка идет в тот же тип который и был в классе, obj не может в инт.
Можно ли как нибудь это делать динамически?
При этом все типы Я уже получаю.

```
Type? typeField = bookTypes.GetField(item.Name).FieldType;
```

Вот только этот не получается првести используя

```
 typeProperty.SetValue(book, (typeField )getValue);
```

Нужна помощь друзья. Ниже весь код

```
//Get type class
Type bookTypes = typeof(Book);

FieldInfo[] fields = bookTypes.GetFields();

List<TypeOfClass> typesClass = new();

foreach (FieldInfo item in fields)
{
    Type? typeField = bookTypes.GetField(item.Name).FieldType;
    typesClass.Add(new TypeOfClass(item.Name, typeField, false));
}

PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = bookTypes.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo item in propertyInfos)
{
    MemberTypes mt = item.MemberType;

    Type? typeProperty = bookTypes.GetProperty(item.Name).PropertyType;
    typesClass.Add(new TypeOfClass(item.Name, typeProperty, true));
}
```

Заполнение

```
Book book = new();

foreach (TypeOfClass item in typesClass)
{
    if (item.IsProperty)
    {
        Type? type = item.TypeValue;
        bool f = type is int;//always false
        PropertyInfo? typeProperty = bookTypes.GetProperty(item.NameValue);
        Type? t = typeProperty.PropertyType;
        object? getValue = Convert.ChangeType("111", item.TypeValue);
        typeProperty.SetValue(book, (Тут нужен каст иначе ошибка)getValue);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Не понял вопроса, текст ошибки приведите и строчку, в которой она возникает. Кстати `type is int` всегда будет `false`, потому что `true` это `type is Type`. Проверяется так `type == typeof(int)`. А так нужен воспроизводимый пример, потому что этот код работает с сферическим классом в вакууме, используя данные такого же происхожения. Как это запустить? Что должен делать этот код?

Comment: Тогда Я немного уточню. Нам надо заполнить поля класса используя рефлексию, но Мы представляем так что Мы не знаем какие там типы и типы могут меняться или добавляться в строчку `  object? getValue = Convert.ChangeType("111", item.TypeValue);
        typeProperty.SetValue(book, (Тут нужен каст иначе ошибка)getValue);`. Только представим что поля в классе могу добавляться а могут исчезать. Могу ли Я динамически привести к типу поля? Ошибка инвалид каст. Мы же распаковываем обж в ну допустим инт, а это нельзя

Comment: Очевидно невозможно, вы не можете из строки `"111"` сделать значение произвольного типа. Например, `DateTime` или `Task`. Функция `Convert.ChangeType` кое-что может, но она далеко не всесильна.